# MySQL: Select all fields while defining a variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

Very simple concept. I am selecting specific rows based on the date they where generated (X days ago) and organizing them by the time frame (in this case, the variable is OVERDUEDAYS). The only problem I am having now is defining OVERDUEDAYS and also selecting the entire rows content without having to define each column in the select statement.

Without further ado (this is what I am hoping to achieve):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(date_generated)) AS OVERDUEDAYS, * FROM invoices WHERE 
    (DATE(date_generated) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
OR 
    DATE(date_generated) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
OR
DATE(date_generated) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 45 DAY)
OR
    DATE(date_generated) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 53 DAY)
OR
    DATE(date_generated) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY))
AND 
    (paid=0 AND cancelled=0)
```

The query works great when you remove the wildcard and define each column manually... But that is a lot of columns and I would like to avoid that at all costs. Suggestions?

Comment: What error do you have with the current query?

Comment: @peter.petrov I am receiving a syntax error. Nothing specific.

Comment: `MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM invoices WHERE 
    (DATE(date_generated) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 D' at line 1`

Comment: can you try replace `*` with `invoices.*` ?

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE colunm_id IN (
    SELECT colunm_id FROM invoices WHERE 
        (DATE(date_generated) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
           OR 
        DATE(date_generated) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
           OR
        DATE(date_generated) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 45 DAY)
           OR
        DATE(date_generated) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 53 DAY)
           OR
        DATE(date_generated) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY))
           AND 
        (paid=0 AND cancelled=0)
)
```

Comment: What in the world? Not to sound like a jerk here... but did you even read my OP?